# How to improve the match pattern to extract second item of a list in Ocaml

Tags: ocaml

I have a list with two items, say `[1;2]`. I try to extract second item by this code.

```
let _::b::_ = [1;2] in b
```

Compiler gives warning `Warning 8: this pattern-matching is not exhaustive. Here is an example of a case that is not matched: (_::[]|[])`

Though it's sensible, I would rather like to know how can we do better. May there be without warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a downside of OCaml's exhaustiveness checking for patterns. In almost all cases it's incredibly useful, but in a few cases you'd like to use a pattern that isn't exhaustive. I.e., in cases where you know the possible values are limited in some way.

If you're absolutely positive your list has at least 2 elements you can use `List.nth`:

```
# List.nth [1; 2] 1;;
- : int = 2
```

However this only works for extracting one value from a list, not in general.

You can turn off the exhaustiveness warning:

```
# let [@warning "-8"] _ :: b :: _ = [1; 2] in b;;
- : int = 2
```

You can write an exhaustive pattern, which is what I usually do myself:

```
# match [1; 2] with
  | _ :: b :: _ -> b
  | _ -> assert false ;;
- : int = 2
```